# How to import a TypeScript module definition for a global third-party library

Tags: typescript

I am using a third-party Javascript library that has to be imported directly via a `<script>` tag in my index.html file. As the library is in my `public/` folder, Typescript (v3.8.3) is able to find it.

The library looks like this:

```
var MyLib = {x: ..., y: ... z:...}
MyLib.SomeFunc = ...
MyLib.SomeOtherFunc = ...
```

When I use `MyLib` in my Typescript project (as a global, no `import` statement), Typescript recognizes MyLib as having the properties `X, Y Z`, but not `SomeFunc` and `SomeOtherFunc`.

To fix this, there exists a typings file, `mylib.d.ts`.

It looks like this:

```
export = MyLib;

declare module MyLib {
  function SomeFunc ...;
  ...
}
```

I added `mylib.d.ts` to my src root, where my other `*.d.ts` files are.

However, Typescript does **not** pick this up. It sticks to the inferences it has made by reading the `MyLib.js` file directly.

How can I get Typescript to read these definitions?

**What I have tried:**

- `/// <reference types="../myLib"`. Typescript still uses the auto-generated types from the actual `myLib.js` file
- `import "../myLib";`. Doesn't work because it's just a typing file, not a module.
- `import type MyLib from "../myLib";`. This seems to not be valid Typescript yet, although it seemed like it was going to be in v3.8. I'm not sure if that's correct anyway, because MyLib is a namespace, not a type.

Answer (score 0):

If typings are in npm then include @types/mylib.d.ts into devDependencies of your package.json file then compiler will not have an issue with:

```
import '../myLib';
```

Otherwise add folder where *.d.ts files are located into compilerOptions / typeRoots array located in tsconfig.json. It should already have "node_modules/@types". For example:

```
    "typeRoots": [
        "myLibTypesFolder",
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
```

Comment: NPM can't find `@types/myLib.d.ts`. It's distributed separately. (The actual project is Google's Blockly, here's their typings file: https://github.com/google/blockly/tree/master/typings

Comment: Updated the answer to add the case of package not being an npm @types.

Comment: The typing file I added is in `src/`, which is also where my other *.d.ts files are. Adding `["src", "node_modules/@types"] does not seem to have an effect: the compiler still ignores the typing file in favor of what it has generated from the `public/myLib.js` file directly.

Comment: Do not mix actual source files and type defines, it may confuse ts.